How to force SIM to use 4G
I have an Android phone with 2 SIM slots - however, it requires me to select 1 sim for data, and whichever SIM is not being used for data is forced to use 2G. Is there a way I can force the phone to use both SIMs on 4G?

What phone are you talking about (or how old is the phone)? If the non-primary SIM is forced to 2G, then this is usually a hardware limitation. Modern phones should support 4G for both SIMs as in a several countries 2G and 3G are already gone...

Related/possible dupe depending on the device capability: Enable 4G on dual SIMs simultaneously (Jio & Airtel) - Samsung Galaxy On Max

@Robert Its called the Fig Flip II, my friend tried the same thing and both SIMs had 4G...
